# Исключить из выборки некоторые данные

Tags: mysql, sql

Хотелось бы внести уточнение в один небольшой нюанс, с которым я постоянно сталкиваюсь в своей практике. Например. Чтобы получить список всех предприятий Москвы, мы делаем запрос:

```sql
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE `city`='MOSCOW'
```

Но как должен выглядеть запрос, если мы хотим получить список всех предприятий в любом городе, кроме Москвы? У меня два варианта:

```sql
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE `city`!='MOSCOW'
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE NOT `city` IN ('MOSCOW')
```

Что на этот счёт думают грамотные программисты? Какой должна быть запись?

Comment: Я за первый вариант, в случае одного города. А вы проверяли второй вариант?

Comment: Оба варианта работают. Но мне интересно, как будет правильнее. А может быть даже есть и какой-то третий вариант. На одном из форумов, мне однажды сделали замечание, относительно некорректности первого варианта. С тех пор я пребываю в сомнениях.

Comment: а что нам говорит `EXPLAIN SELECT company FROM table_1 WHERE city!='MOSCOW'` и `EXPLAIN SELECT company FROM table_1 WHERE NOT city IN ('MOSCOW')`

Comment: Как оказалось, в обоих вариантах EXPLAIN показывает абсолютно идентичные результаты. Что видимо должно указывать на отсутствие какой-либо разницы между ними.

Comment: А что если перед городами будит стоять страна ка тогда быть?

Answer (score 3):

Реальной разницы нет. Оптимизатор все эти варианты все равно сведет к одному результату.

Можете попробовать проверить через `EXPLAIN`, если интересно. Если есть индексы, то будет использоваться `range`, т.к. предполагает перебор всех элементов, не входящих в некоторое множество (пусть даже состоящее из одного элемента), поэтому разницы между `NOT city IN ('MOSCOW')` и `city!='MOSCOW'` не будет.

Но с другой стороны есть пара принципиальных моментов:

1. Если вдруг есть вероятность, что будет расширяться запрос, и придется добавлять доп. города в условие, лучше оставляйте `NOT city IN ('MOSCOW')`.
2. Если же есть возможность изначально передать полный набор городов, не трогая при этом каждый раз бд, то лучше преобразовать запрос в прямое вхождение, например, `city IN ('Saint Petersburg', 'Novosibirsk')`. Такая логика не всегда возможна и оправдана, но во многих запросах может давать ощутимый прирост производительности.

Answer (score 2):

все три варианта корректны:

```sql
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE `city`!='MOSCOW'
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE NOT `city` IN ('MOSCOW')
SELECT `company` FROM `table_1` WHERE `city` NOT IN ('MOSCOW')
```

подтверждение:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b392f/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table t (c text);
insert into t values ('москва'), ('бологое'), ('ленинград');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t where c != 'москва'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b392f/1/0)**:

```
|         c |
|-----------|
|   бологое |
| ленинград |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from t where not c in ('москва')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b392f/1/1)**:

```
|         c |
|-----------|
|   бологое |
| ленинград |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from t where c not in ('москва')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b392f/1/2)**:

```
|         c |
|-----------|
|   бологое |
| ленинград |
```